How can I prove that theorem in coq: (x | a) -> (x | b) -> x <= (gcd a b)?
I have this realization of greatest common divisor:
Fixpoint gcd_ (m n d : nat) : nat :=
match d with
| 0 => if (m =? 0) then n else m
| S k => if (m mod S k =? 0) && (n mod S k =? 0) then S k else gcd_ m n k
end.
Definition gcd (m n : nat) : nat := gcd_ m n (min m n).

And I have to prove specification for this:
Theorem gcd_spec :
  forall a b x : nat, (x | a) -> (x | b) -> x <= (gcd a b).

But I have no idea how to do it at all. I will be glad for some help please.
I was thinking about start my proof like that:
Theorem gcd_spec :
  forall a b x : nat, divide x a -> divide x b -> x <= (gcd a b).
Proof.
intros. induction a as [| a' AH]; induction b as [| b' BH].

But I don't even know how to complete first subgoal.

you have quite an unusual definition of gcd. is that required and on purpose or by chance?

Um, the statement you're trying to prove doesn't even seem to be true.
From Coq Require Import Utf8 PeanoNat ssrbool ssrfun ssreflect.
Import Nat.

Theorem not_gcd_spec : ¬ ∀ a b x : nat, (x | a) → (x | b) → x ≤ gcd a b.
Proof.
  move=> /(_ 0 0 1) H; apply /(nle_succ_0 0) /H; by exists 0.
Qed.


I suppose it is an assignment, so I'm reluctant to give a complete answer (I can add more details later, if one asks).
Double induction is often a bad idea. Here you need to prove intermediary results about your gcd_ function, something like :
Theorem gcd_correct (a b k : nat) : (gcd_ a b k) <= k /\
  (forall i, (i <= k /\ divide i a /\ divide i b -> i <= (gcd_ a b k)).
Proof.
Admitted.

This one should be provable with an induction on k (because gcd_ itself is defined by induction on k).
